# Why are p-values misleading after performing a stepwise selection?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, data-mining, stepwise-regression

Let's consider for example a linear regression model. I heard that, in data mining, after performing a stepwise selection based on the AIC criterion, it is misleading to look at the p-values to test the null hypothesis that each true regression coefficient is zero. I heard that one should consider all the variables left in the model as having a true regression coefficient different from zero instead. Can anyone explain me why? Thank you.

Comment: [Here is more information. The references cited there are also helpful.](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/)

Comment: In https://theoreticalecology.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/yes-statistical-errors-are-slowing-down-scientific-progress/ , I show some R code demonstrating the type-I inflation after AIC selection. Note that it doesn't matter if it's stepwise or global, the point is that model selection is basically multiple testing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> after performing a stepwise selection based on the AIC criterion, it is misleading to look at the p-values to test the null hypothesis that each true regression coefficient is zero.

Indeed, p-values represent the probability of seeing a test statistic at least as extreme as the one you have, when the null hypothesis is true. If $H_0$ is true, the p-value should have a uniform distribution.

But after stepwise selection (or indeed, after a variety of other approaches to model selection), the p-values of those terms that remain in the model don't have that property, even when we know that the null hypothesis is true.

This happens because we choose the variables that have or tend to have small p-values (depending on the precise criteria we used). This means that the p-values of the variables left in the model are typically much smaller than they would be if we'd fitted a single model. Note that selection will on average pick models that seem to fit even better than the true model, if the class of models includes the true model, or if the class of models is flexible enough to closely approximate the true model.

[In addition and for basically the same reason, the coefficients that remain are biased away from zero and their standard errors are biased low; this in turn impacts confidence intervals and predictions as well -- our prediction intervals will be too narrow for example.]

To see these effects, we can take multiple regression where some population coefficients are 0 and some are not, perform a stepwise procedure and then for those models that contain variables that had zero coefficients, look at the p-values that result.

(In the same simulation, you can look at the estimates and the standard deviations for the coefficients and discover the ones that correspond to non-zero coefficients are also impacted.)

In short, it's not appropriate to consider the usual p-values as meaningful.

> I heard that one should consider all the variables left in the model as significant instead.

As to whether all the values in the model after stepwise should be 'regarded as significant', I'm not sure the extent to which that's a useful way to look at it. What is "significance" intended to mean then?

---

Here's the result of running R's `stepAIC` with default settings on 1000 simulated samples with n=100, and ten candidate variables (none of which are related to the response). In each case the number of terms left in the model was counted:

[image]

Only 15.5% of the time was the correct model chosen; the rest of the time the model included terms that were not different from zero. If it's actually possible that there are zero-coefficient variables in the set of candidate variables, we are likely to have several terms where the true coefficient is zero in our model. As a result, it's not clear it's a good idea to regard all of them as non-zero.

Comment: With the sentence "I heard that one should consider all the variables left in the model as significant instead" I meant: "I heard that one should consider all the variables left in the model as having a true regression coefficient different form zero instead"

Comment: Okay; I've added the results of a simulation that speaks to that.

Comment: +1 I was doing the same simulations this weekend to prepare for a class on model selection methods.  I obtained the same patterns of results, exploring $k=3$ to $39$ variables and using $10k$ observations.  The next step is to see what a Bonferroni correction might do ... .

Comment: @whuber indeed, seeing what effect a Bonferroni would have (on a variety of aspects of the problem) was my immediate inclination on completing the above simulation as well, but it's not what people actually tend to do with stepwise so I didn't address it here. I'd be fascinated to hear you discuss model selection methods. I expect I'd learn quite a bit.

Comment: @Glen_b: (Quoted from your answer)This means that the p-values of the variables left in the model are typically much smaller than they would be if we'd fitted a single model even "if the one model we fit happens to be the one that generated the data, whether the true model is null or not". Can you explain the highlighted part a bit? How it can be that the p-values are smaller in the model that has the same specification as the data generating process (true model)?

Comment: @shani Re-reading what's written there doesn't quite make sense; if it said something slightly different to that, it would be okay, but I'd need to figure out a good rephrase. I'll remove that and see if I can explain the issue better.

Comment: @Glen_b, this concept is very confusing to me. It almost implies that a model that was built via stepwise selection will yield different coefficient p-values than the same model, had it been chosen via domain knowledge. I know that this is not what you're saying but this is kind of the sense I'm making, probably because I'm missing something. Could you please point me to a simulated example of this concept?

Comment: Strictly, the p-value of a specific model on a dataset (if calculated the usual way) will be the same both ways but the value will no longer mean the same thing; the *population distribution* of p-values you get under the null is shifted downward by selection (you eliminate large ones), so it can't be compared with a significance level for a test (not one with suitable properties at least). If you were to adjust for that effect, you'd have to shift the p-values up (the population of selected p-values under the null is artificially low).

Answer (score 9):

An analogy may help.  Stepwise regression when the candidate variables are indicator (dummy) variables representing mutually exclusive categories (as in ANOVA) corresponds exactly to choosing which groups to combine by finding out which groups are minimally different by $t$-tests.  If the original ANOVA was tested against $F_{p-1, n-p-1}$ but the final collapsed groups are tested against $F_{q-1, n-q-1}$ where $q < p$ the resulting statistic does **not** have an $F$ distribution and the false positive probability will be out of control.

Comment: I've read this in your book but I'm still grasping to understand in what ways do p-values get biased. To my understanding, the stepwise-selected model will yield the same coefficient p-value had it been selected via domain knowledge, and this is the part that confuses me. Could you please point me to a simulated example where p-value bias can be shown empirically?

Comment: There are two ways to think about this.  First, if you have a hundred candidate variables and all 100 are random vectors, you will easily find a few variables with very small p-values when computed the usual way.  The "impressive" variables you find with this process have their nominal p-values computed devoid of context, not accounting for the number of candidate variables.  These p-values are misleading.  Second, go bad to the basic definition: p=P(finding something more extreme than one you found | $H_0$).  The "more extreme" must consider context.